# How to embed onclick into another function

Tags: javascript

I want to implement this logic:
while the mouse move on one element with id `"spirit"`, sleep a while then change 
the element's position. But if user click the element in the `"sleep period"`, alert a message.

So here is what my code like:

```
    function changePos() {


        let img = document.getElementById("spirit");


        // "sleep"
        let now = new Date().getTime();
        while ( new Date().getTime() < now + 1000 ){

            if (img.onclick == true){
                alert("Click Success")
            }

        }

        // change position
        img.style.left = Math.random()*innerWidth+"px";
        img.style.top = Math.random()*innerHeight+"px";

    }
```

The bug is: when I click the element, there is no reaction. While it change position normally.

Any advice on it?

Comment: The `onclick` means something completely different than what your code expects. It indicates a *function* to be called when a "click" event fires. Code to do what you describe would be very different from what you posted here.

Comment: See https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp for examples

Comment: This will hang your browser for 1 second, better to embrace JS scheduling functions and adapt them to your needs.

Comment: This is wrong on too many assumptions to count. `onclick` is not a state value, it's an event handler. Javascript is a single-thread message-driven event loop, so you can't achieve "sleep" by looping over nothing, that will just hang the execution thread (just like in any language I know), no events will be processed. You can't even use `sleep()` style functions, you need to use callback timing events such as `setTimeout()`. It's basically a "how do I write code" kind of qusetion...

Comment: @Dinu Since you have realized it is about "how to write code" kind of question, I think if you could do some real help like editing question or give some advice on how to do that I would be more grateful. Comment is cheap, help is cher~

Comment: @Martin521Wang - right, but it's outside the scope of StackOverflow. If some user is willing to do that effort (like I see below) kudos to them, you should be grateful, but you certainly shouldn't expect that. As per the declared scope, you are supposed to make efforts to write your code and not ask for tutorials or come with a piece of code that is not reasonably expected to do anything and ask what's wrong with it. It's like I would write this in javascript: `I(don't/konw@how^to#do#this()` then ask people why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve your goal, you'll likely need to mainly work with the `setTimeout` function which executes a callback function (its `1st` parameter) after a certain number of milliseconds (its `2nd` parameter). Also, you'll need to attach two different events to `#spirit` to manipulate a global (not really but I mean accessible by all the events handlers) variable, let's call it `allowClick` for example, which works as a flag for showing the message when clicked or not. The events are :

- `mouseenter` event : it fires as soon as the mouse hovers the element (`#spirit` in our case) and it calls a handler that does the following :

  1. set `allowClick` variable to `true` to allow the message to appear after click.
  2. starts a timer with `setTimeout` function that waits for a specified number of seconds then the callback (remember `1st` parameter of `setTimeout`) comes in to clear the timer, sets `allowClick` to false so no message after click then it applies a `top` and `left` translation based on a random number.
- `click` event : if `allowClick` flag is `true` show the message, otherwise do nothing.

To illustrate, here's a demo, it contains some helpful comments :

> from your code, the `#spirit` element seems to be an image so I used a [placeholder image](https://placeholder.com) trying to simulate your situation.
>
> in the demo, in order to make choosing the time to wait nearly dynamic I used a `data-wait-until` attribute for the image that contains the number of seconds (in milliseconds in fact) to wait before making the translations (`top` and `left` attributes) that will be used by `JavaScript`. Anyway, if this attribute is kept undefined, a fallback to one second is used automatically.
>
> also, in order for `top` and `left` to be applied, the image **must** be positioned (has a `position` rule other than `static`).

```js
/**
* img: the "#spirit" image.
* allowClick: a flag to distingush between showing a message after click or not.  
**/

const img = document.getElementById('spirit');
let allowClick;

/** attach "mouseenter" listener to the image **/
img.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
  /** instantly allow clicking (the message to appear) **/
  allowClick = true;
  
  /** the timer that waits till the waiting delay to finish in order to move the element (translating) **/
  let timer = window.setTimeout(() => {
    /** the callback function (remember "1st" parameter) **/
    
    /** stop the timer **/
    window.clearTimeout(timer);
    
    /** no messages will be shown from now on after clicking the image **/
    allowClick = false;
    
    /** move the image **/
    img.style.top = Math.ceil(Math.random() * img.offsetHeight) + 'px';
    img.style.left = Math.ceil(Math.random() * img.offsetWidth) + 'px';
  }, +img.dataset.waitUntil || 1000);
}); /** "+img.dataset.waitUntil || 1000": that's the delay ("2nd" parameter) and it uses the "data-wait-until" attribute of the image or 1000 milliseconds (1 second) if omitted **/

/** attach click event to the image **/
img.addEventListener('click', () => allowClick && alert('Clicked !')); /** if the flag "allowClick" is true show the message **/
```

```css
/** for demo purposes **/
img {
  position: relative; /** allow top and left attributes to be applied **/
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 2px solid #181818;
  transition: all .4s 0s ease;
}
```

```html
<!-- added a "data-wait-until" attribute to the image that you can use to change the delay time before translating takes place per yor requirement -->

<!-- if you ommit it 1 second delay is used instead -->

<!-- in this demo I applied a 1 second delay by using data-wait-until="1000" (1000 ms = 1s) -->

<p class="info">hover/click the next image and see what happens</p>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" id="spirit" title="hover or click me !" data-wait-until="1000" />
```

> anyway, the image still moves even after clicking it to get the message (and of course the delay ended) as you didn't tell us what to do when the image is clicked : do moving or cancel it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var timeOutVariable = null;
var timeOutDuration = yourtimeoutduration;
document.getElementById("spirit").onmouseover = function(){
     if (timeOutVariable !== null) {
         clearTimeout(timeOutVariable );
     }
     timeOutVariable = setTimeout(function(){
         document.getElementById("spirit").style.left = Math.random()*innerWidth+"px";
         document.getElementById("spirit").style.top = Math.random()*innerHeight+"px";
     }, timeOutDuration);
}

document.getElementById("spirit").onclick = function(){
    if (timeOutVariable !== null) {
         clearTimeout(timeOutVariable );
         timeOutVariable = null;
     }
    alert("Click success");
};
```